# KnockoutJS get result html of template

Tags: knockout.js

How to get compiled html of template in knockout?
I have some template, like this:

```
<!-- ko foreach: someViewModel -->
<input data-bind="{ attr: { id: code, ... }}" />
<!-- /ko -->
```

On result html page in Chrome Inspector I can see only text:

```
<!-- ko foreach: someViewModel --><!-- /ko -->
```

How to get result html of template?

Comment: *"How to get result html of template?"* - You can always look at the `.innerHTML` of any node in the DOM with JavaScript. But that's a suspicious thing to ask - what are you planning to do?

Comment: ![screenshot](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/61776819/150835999-211262f4-fa13-46c6-96bf-9d1b1c062f2c.png)  I need to see final html generated by template. In Console I did: console.log($0.innerHTML)  but it output only text like in screenshot

Comment: There is only one explanation: `ratings` is non-existent or empty at this point, otherwise there would be something in-between those comments.

Comment: Yes `ratings` was empty. Sorry my fault

Comment: <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>

Add this as an HTML element in your DOM. It's pretty handy